# Stanardize only a few selected columns in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, sklearn-pandas

I have a CSV file out of which only a few columns need normalization(others are binary values). Should I selectively normalize the required columns or should I normalize all the columns in the table? If I normalize the entire table will I lose some information or noise is introduced into data that don't require any normalization or standardization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make some points clear.

- Binary Data is a categorical data (IsEmployed - 0/1)
- Only numerical data has to be normalized

Understanding part:

- When we say normalized data, it means we are moving distribution
  scale to range of 0-1.

+Added:

- In perspective of Categorical data, we do **OneHotEncoding** and convert it back to binary data for each category.